# Get attribute of object with the string name

Tags: python, string, function

How do I get the attribute value of an object when I have a string of the attribute name that I want?  For example, suppose `cmd_i` has attributes `q0` and `q1`.  I'd like to be able to do this:

```
for x in range(2):                 
    print('cmd_i.q{}'.format(x))
```

Instead of having to do this:

```
print(cmd_i.q0)
print(cmd_i.q1)
```

Comment: What is cmd_i for you ? What are the value excepted to obtain with cmd_i.q0/1 ? We need more precision to provide you an answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr) to get attribute values of objects using strings:

```
class Test:
    q1 = 2
    q2 = 3
    q3 = 'a'

>>> x = Test()
>>> x.q1
2
>>> getattr(x, 'q2')
3
```

And with an f-string:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 4):
...     print(f'q{i}', getattr(x, f'q{i}'))
...
q1 2
q2 3
q3 a
```

You can also pass a default value to return if the attribute doesn't exist (instead of raising an `AttributeError`):

```
>>> getattr(x, 'q0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'q0'
# vs
>>> for i in range(1, 4):
...     print(f'q{i}', getattr(x, f'q{i}', None))
...
q0 None
q1 2
q2 3
q3 a
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible using the `eval` function, but doesn't seem to be considered good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909510/

```py
a = 7
eval('a')
```